# How to install gcc make perl package in virtual box with rhel 7.5 os

Tags: virtualbox, rhel7

I couldn't install guest addition on virtual box version 5.2.12 error caused-
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the gcc make perl packages from your distribution.

Answer (score 33):

You can use the below command to install the packages in RHEL 7.

```
yum install gcc perl make
```

Virtual box is base for the RHEL, all packes should be installed in RHEL OS only.
Hope you set the repository and your VM have access to internet

Comment: It is work.i want install virtual guast additions but error arrise gcc make perl not installed. So it is very good for me.
Thanks a lot...

Comment: But on Ubuntu the repo list is empty, how to get the repo list ?

Comment: For UBUNTU sudo apt install gcc perl make

Comment: as Ubunto user i used: `sudo apt-get install gcc perl make`